# Restriction on Range

Tags: scala, scala-collections

i'm surprised. Why was made restriction of implementation to type Range, is whose the size limited by Int.MaxValue?
Thanks.

Comment: Because `Range` is not parametrized and uses `Int` in internals?
`new Range (start: Int, end: Int, step: Int)`

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Range

Comment: And? It's obviously, but why not used Long?

Comment: Could you check the answers again?

Answer (score 5):

From the [`NumericRange` docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange),

> `NumericRange` is a more generic version of the `Range` class which works
>   with arbitrary types. It must be supplied with an `Integral`
>   implementation of the range type.
>
> Factories for likely types include `Range.BigInt`, `Range.Long`, and
>   `Range.BigDecimal`. `Range.Int` exists for completeness, but the `Int`-based
>   `scala.Range` should be more performant.
>
> ```
> val r1 = new Range(0, 100, 1)
> val veryBig = Int.MaxValue.toLong + 1
> val r2 = Range.Long(veryBig, veryBig + 100, 1)
> assert(r1 sameElements r2.map(_ - veryBig))
> ```

Comment: Imho this doesn't answer the question which was about the allowed size and not about the types which can be used as elements.

Comment: @soc You are right, of course. In the first priority i'm interested for whatever reason the allowed size of range made 2^31. Probably the reasons lie in the design of collection...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the other answer is just wrong.

It demonstrates that you can use other number types, but this doesn't change the fact that a `Range` can only hold `2³¹` elements, like every other collection in Scala/Java.

As far as I know there is no real rationale behind this design decision. Having 64-bit collections would be certainly nice and support for arrays with 64bit indices are common for Java, but it is hard to integrate that into the existing language/collection framework. Some people say that the JVM is limited to a total of 4 billion objects, but I couldn't verify that.